# Font awesome with the class: fas fa-user gives pack a rectangle instead of a plus sign (+)

Tags: html, css, extjs, font-awesome, sencha-architect

According to this page: https://fontawesome.com/icons/plus?style=solid

```
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
```

should give a plus sign (+)

And according to this page: https://fontawesome.com/icons/user?style=solid

```
<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
```

should give a user sign

Instead they both return a rectangle. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine. Maybe you included the fontawesome css file incorrectly.

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
<i class="fas fa-user"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it turns out I just had to replace fas with fa. I don't know why but works for me!

Comment: @gerbenschipper You are probably using fontawesome version 4

Answer (score -1):

Look up for fas in the css loaded in your browser. You should see the diff

Comment: I don't actually have it opened in my browser. I'm watching in Sencha-architect version 3.5.1